# Get the name with most repeated numbers value in table

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to calculate how much some names repeated and to get he most repeated name out but cannot get it. I can calculate how much Michael has $fix in his rows. But I need who is the best of it in repeats.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM (SELECT * FROM names WHERE league='books' and $position='Michael' ORDER BY id LIMIT $limit) AS last12 WHERE $fix='1'
```

I want to print me Michael if he repeats the most:

```
Michael 1
Jack 1
Jack 1
Jack 1
Michael 1
Michael 1
Michael 1
Juni 1
```

Comment: Your query and results make no sense.  The query selects only `'Michael'` for instance.  And, the query only has one column.  Provide better examples of sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can do that by doing: select count(*) as count group by name assuming that name is the column that contains the names (Michael, Juni, etc.) Then you can find out who has the highest count

Comment: @Erick Can you give me example please

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just give example because it will select all, not just Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a table called names with columns id, name, league, etc. You want to know how many Michael or Erick or whatever name are there. To do that, you need to group by that column and use count(*), like follows:

```
Select name, count(*) as count from names group by name
```

This will return the names with its respective counts.

Comment: I would add an `order by count(name) desc` to get the name with the highest occurrence as the first result.

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd yes that is a good idea, depending on the need. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It print me all names and values of $fix

Comment: I need to count numbers how much is there some 1, not how much Michael repeats, how much number repeats. I repeats 10x for Michael and he has the high repeat, print Michael